# how to get Current date and time on to a SharePoint edit form SP2019

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-designer

I have a request for one of my sites to make it so that a when a user opens the edit form the current datetime is displayed as part of one of the fields it the edit form.

Idea is the person who opens the edit form will copy this field called "Label" and paste it's contents to print out a label.

Currently the "Label" field is a single line of text column that I have a workflow concatenating two existing fields (one single line of text, the other is a person/group) and I want to add the current datetime when the user opens the edit form, so it can be copied.

Form is currently not an info path from and I would prefer to keep it that way. Is this possible?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

As you are using SharePoint 2019, I assume you are using modern experience. In modern experience, without PowerApps, we are not able to customize the edit form to make a date & time column to be filled with current time `Now()` when user edit it. The column default value works on new form as which you have tried. If classic experience also works for you, you can try to add a js script to set the field value when edit form loaded.

And as you goal is to get a label with current time, I will say just using the workflow to add the current time when item is modified. It will be much easier to add the time to the string you have made with `concat()`